# docker-compose.yml for elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, kibana

My aim is to get the elasticsearch and kibana images from DockerHub working locally using Docker.

This does the trick and works perfectly...

```
docker network create mynetwork --driver=bridge

docker run -p 5601:5601 --name kibana -d --network mynetwork kibana 
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name elasticsearch -d --network mynetwork elasticsearch
```

Today a bird whispered in my ear and said I should learn docker-compose. So I tried to do all of what's above inside a docker-compose.yml.

Here is my attempt.

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - docker_elk
  kibana:
    image: kibana:latest
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - docker_elk
networks:
  docker_elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I've been racking my brains as to why I always get the ECONNREFUSED error as shown below when i run docker-compse up.

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting training_elasticsearch_1
Recreating training_kibana_1
Attaching to training_elasticsearch_1, training_kibana_1
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:55,798][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: your kernel is buggy and you should upgrade
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:56,036][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] version[2.4.1], pid[1], build[c67dc32/2016-09-27T18:57:55Z]
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:56,036][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] initializing ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:56,713][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Caliban] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:56,749][INFO ][env                      ] [Caliban] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/vda2)]], net usable_space [54.8gb], net total_space [59gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:56,749][INFO ][env                      ] [Caliban] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:kibana@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch"],"pid":11,"message":"Request error, retrying -- connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:9200"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:kbn_vislib_vis_types@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":11,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":11,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@1.0.0","error"],"pid":11,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:markdown_vis@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:metric_vis@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:spyModes@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:statusPage@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["status","plugin:table_vis@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:39:58Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":11,"message":"Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601"}
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:58,515][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] initialized
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:58,515][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] starting ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:58,587][INFO ][transport                ] [Caliban] publish_address {172.20.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:39:58,594][INFO ][discovery                ] [Caliban] elasticsearch/1Cf9qz7CSCqHBEEuwG7PQw
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:40:00Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":11,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:40:00Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":11,"message":"No living connections"}
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:40:01,650][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Caliban] new_master {Caliban}{1Cf9qz7CSCqHBEEuwG7PQw}{172.20.0.2}{172.20.0.2:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:40:01,661][INFO ][http                     ] [Caliban] publish_address {172.20.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:40:01,661][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] started
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:40:01,798][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Caliban] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
elasticsearch_1  | [2016-11-02 22:40:02,149][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Caliban] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana][0]] ...]).
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-11-02T22:40:03Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@1.0.0","info"],"pid":11,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Kibana index ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping training_kibana_1 ... done
Stopping training_elasticsearch_1 ... done
```

Can someone please help me with why?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried re-starting Kibana? Maybe elasticsearch isn't fully up when Kibana tries to connect to it?

Comment: Hi @R0MANARMY. I think you are right. Can you check the extra information I've put in the logs to confirm. Your comment has prompted me to add some extra log information to illustrate more about what's happening. Is the fix to add a start dependency or sequence in docker-compose files? How would you do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To add the hard dependency on elasticsearch for kibana, you need the **depends_on** variable to be set as shown below. Also, to add to @Phil McMillan's answer, you can set the elasticsearch_url variable in kibana,  *without* static addressing using [Docker's inbuilt DNS mechanism](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks).

```
version: '2.1'
services:
     elasticsearch:
       image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
       container_name: elasticsearch
       networks:
           docker-elk:

     kibana:
       image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.3
       container_name: kibana
       environment:
          - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200"
       networks:
          - docker-elk
       depends_on:
          - elasticsearch

networks:
  docker-elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Note the environment variable ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200 just uses has the container name (elasticsearch) which the Docker DNS server is able to resolve.

Comment: This answer is mega out of date now

Answer (score 16):

You need to include the `links`.

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - docker_elk
  kibana:
    image: kibana:latest
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - docker_elk
networks:
  docker_elk:
    driver: bridge
```

**UPDATED**

When using the image `elasticsearch:latest`, it's Elasticsearch `5.0` and requires us to increase our Docker host virtual memory.

Before running the `docker-compose`, please make sure to run this command on your Docker host.

Linux:

```
su root
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Windows (boot2docker)

```
docker-machine ssh default
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

If you don't want to change your Docker host, just use the Elasticsearch `2.x` image at `elasticsearch:2`

Comment: Hi, I tried that. But I still get the same error. I'm thinking it might more be to do with elasticsearch not being fully initialised before kibana comes up. As per the comment by @R0MANARMY. I've edited my original post to show some more logs which I think might illustrate the problem better.

Comment: Hi @Tuan. I thought the services running on the same network was enough to get them talking. In fact I thought networks was the successor to links? But are you saying you need to use both together?

Comment: @Richie, the best way to check is going into the kibana container. Starting with the ```docker-compose -d up```. Access the kibana by ```docker exec -it training_kibana_1 /bin/bash```, then ```curl http://elasticsearch:9200/```.

Comment: @Richie, do you get this error in Elasticsearch ```max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]``` ? If yes, we should increase the vm.max_map_count in our Docker host. I updated my answer.

Comment: no I don't get that error. Nethertheless I will try to downgrade my versions of kibana and elasticsearch to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Richie, I re-reviewed your logs. It's ES ```2.4.1```! I believe you had the old images of ES and Kibana. You might need to re-pull them before running docker-compose, like ```docker pull elasticsearch``` and ```docker pull kibana``` .

Comment: To get it to work I had to add the following environment variables `environment:`
`- "discovery.type=single-node"`
           `-"ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"`

Comment: this answer is mega out of date now

Comment: @PiotrKula, yes, it was 2016.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me
`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
    version: '3'
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
        environment:
          - discovery.type=single-node
        ports:
          - 9200:9200
      kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
        ports:
          - 5601:5601
```

Comment: Do you have a compose file for ES 8.2+ - They use service accounts for kibana now I can't work out how to configure that in the compose section

Answer (score 3):

I'm using docker-compose v3 format according to [this post](https://jinnabalu.com/Elasticsearch-Kibana-using-Docker-Compose/):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=es-node
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - local-es:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - es-net

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200"
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - es-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: "unless-stopped"

networks:
  es-net:

volumes:
  local-es:
```

Comment: Do you have a compose file that works with 8.2+ - They changed the way kibana authenticates using a service account now. I don't know how to update the compose file to create that account

Comment: I'd recommend going off the definitive source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/docker.html#docker-file

Answer (score 1):

File `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=es-node
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.5.2
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: 'unless-stopped'

networks:
  elastic:
```

Official documentation:

<kbd>[Install Kibana with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I have this working.  No links are needed and it doesn't have anything to do with elasticsearch starting before kibana.  The issue is that when running under compose, a new bridged network is defined with its own set of IPs.  Kibana needs to communicate with the cluster over this bridged network - "localhost" is not available anymore for the connectivity.

You need to do a couple of things:

1. You need to set a couple of values in kibana.yml or under the environment: section of kibana in the compose file):

a. elasticsearch.url in kibana.yml (or ELASTICSEARCH_URL under the environment: section of kibana in the compose file) must be set to the specific IP of the cluster and port 9200 - localhost will not work, as it does when you run outside of compose.

```
elasticsearch.url: "http://172.16.238.10:9200"
```

b. You also need to set server.host (SERVER_HOST) to the bridged IP of the Kibana container.

```
server.host: "172.16.238.12"
```

Note: you still access the kibana UI from with http://127.0.0.1:5601 and you still need those "ports" commands!

2. You need to set an "ipam" configuration under your bridged network and assign elasticsearch and kibana static ips so that kibana can access it via its configuration above.

Something like this should suffice:

```
elasticsearch:
  networks:
    esnet:
      ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
kibana:
  networks:
    esnet:
      ipv4_address: 172.16.238.12
networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

Don't forget to use one of the documented methods to set Kibana configuration - ELASTICSEARCH_URL is required to be set!

I have a docker compose file that creates two elasticsearch nodes and a kibana instance all running on the same bridged network.  It is possible.

Comment: this answer is mega out of date now